# add sparse matrix in C

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, sparse-matrix

How to add each Sparse matrix properly?
I have two sparse matrix A , and B,,
but I wrote code about `add_matrix` It doesn't work properly

I think the code of printf(" 0"); ruined everything
so How can I wrote function `add_matrix`?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct element{
    int row;
    int col;
    int value;
} element;

typedef struct SparseMatrix {
    element* data;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int terms;
} SparseMatrix;


void matrix_transpose(SparseMatrix a, SparseMatrix *b) 
{
    for (int r = 0; r < (a.terms); r++) {
            b->data[r].row = a.data[r].col;
            b->data[r].col = a.data[r].row;
            b->data[r].value = a.data[r].value;
    }
}

void add_matrix(SparseMatrix a, SparseMatrix b, SparseMatrix* c)
{
    // this part
    for (int i = 0; i < a.terms; i++) {
        c->data[i].value = a.data[i].value + b.data[i].value;
    }
}
    


void print_matrix(SparseMatrix a)
{
    int n = a.rows;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            bool check = false;
            for (int k = 0; k < a.terms; k++)
            {
                if (a.data[k].row == i && a.data[k].col == j)
                {
                    printf("%2d", a.data[k].value);
                    check = true;
                }
            }
            if (!check)
                printf(" 0");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    SparseMatrix A, B, C;

    int n, num; //n*n matrix, num of values

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &num);

    A.cols = n;
    A.rows = n;
    A.terms = num;
    A.data = (element*)malloc(sizeof(element) * num);
    B.rows = n;
    B.cols = n;
    B.terms = num;
    B.data = (element*)malloc(sizeof(element) * num);
    C.rows = n;
    C.cols = n;
    C.data = (element*)malloc(sizeof(element) * num);  
    C.terms = num;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d %d", &A.data[i].row, &A.data[i].col, &A.data[i].value);
    }

    print_matrix(A);

    matrix_transpose(A, &B);

    print_matrix(B);

    add_matrix(A, B, &C);

    print_matrix(C);
    free(A.data);
    free(B.data);
    free(C.data);
    return 0;
}
```

### input

3 3 0 0 3 1 2 5 2 0 7

### desired output

6 0 7
0 0 5
7 5 0

### My code's output

6 0 0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

### What i've debugged

A and B's row, col doesn't change.

Comment: "doesn't work" is never a good problem description. Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result. Also describe what debugging you have done and where you find things start going wrong based on that debugging.

Comment: Test case #1
input : 3 3 0 0 3 1 2 5 2 0 7 
output:
 6 0 7
 0 0 5
 7 5 0

What i've done is rewrite `add_matrix` function.

except `add_matrix` everything is right 
but honestly I don't know what to do at my best

Comment: Please do not put such info in comments. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69325697/edit) the post to update it. Also, you have still only provided one output. Is that the expected or actual output? Please provide both. And how about the debugging?

Comment: I edited post. Is it ok?

Comment: You may have misinterpreted the term "sparse" or what those structure represent. Where, in the add function, the actual positions of the matrix elements are taken into account?

Comment: Um,, B is transpose version of A So I want to add both of A and B to C

Comment: So what do you expect `C.data[0].row` to be, and why?

Answer (score 2):

The function `add_matrx` doesn't take into account the actual positions of the matrix elements:

```
void add_matrix(SparseMatrix a, SparseMatrix b, SparseMatrix* c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.terms; i++) {
    //              ^^^^^^^^^^^
    // Why are you assuming that both the matrices had the same
    // amount of non-zero values? Are you sure that the resulting matrix
    // will have exactly the same number of non-zeroes (in the same places)?

        c->data[i].value = a.data[i].value + b.data[i].value;
        // That may be right IF both a.data[i] and b.data[i] have the same
        // row and column, otherwise you are summing the wrong elements.

        // What are c->data[i].row and c->data[i].col now?
        // Those are not initialized, leading to undefined behavior, e.g. I
        // obtained this result running your program:
        // 61014 0 0
        // 0 0 0
        // 0 0 0
    }
}
```

I'd suggest to sort the matrix elements both by rows and by column after their values are extracted from the stream and before the matrices are used, to make all the algorithms easier (and more efficient).